# Xamarin - MediaRouteButton ShowDialog() method throws NullPointerException (Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, chromecast

I'm trying to implement a MediaRouteButton in Xamarin Android to find ChromeCast devices in the area, which uses the android support library (NuGeT package)
I downloaded a sample app (which works, the CastingCall project sample provided when the GooglePlayServices - Cast component is downloaded), but when I tried to transfer the code over it throws an error when clicking the button as follows:

```
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteChooserDialog.onCreate(MediaRouteChooserDialog.java:167)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:465)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:406)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1986)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Here is some of the code:

```
mediaRouteButton = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.App.MediaRouteButton> (Resource.Id.mediaRouteButton);
mediaRouter = MediaRouter.GetInstance (this);
mediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder ()
            .AddControlCategory (MediaControlIntent.CategoryRemotePlayback)
            .Build();
mediaRouteButton.RouteSelector = mediaRouteSelector;
```

The MediaRouteButton is not greyed out, which means it is detecting the correct routes in the area (I debugged it just to make sure, and the mediaRouter object contains the same routes that shows up in the example app), but it seems to be crashing when trying to create the Dialog which allows the user to choose a route (MediaRouter.ShowDialog()). I couldn't find a fix to this error, as I don't have access to the source code of this class where it seems to be crashing (MediaRouteChooserDialog). I even tried to implement a custom dialog factory (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouteDialogFactory.html) and a custom on click listener, but neither of these seemed to work and it still threw an error when I clicked on the button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue today, all of a sudden. Updating the component to 29.0.0.2 fixed it.

Comment: Updating the component and rebuilding your project should fix this issue. (Usually rebuilding by itself fixes this problem).